# Issue in switching from one activity to other

Tags: android

I have Activity1 Activity2 Activity3 activities in my application.

now I want to switch from Activity3 to Activity1.

How do I proceed?

And also, how to finish an activity from another activity?

Comment: which one is your launcher activity? please provide a little more details.

Comment: Without being more clear, we can't help you. What do you wan't to do ? Keep Home -> A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> A1 or just do Home -> A3 -> A1 ?

Comment: Hey, this is the third time your endings are removed from this question. Please stop it. Endings, taglines and signatures are merely unnecessary noise, please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If you don't stop I will be forced to flag you for moderation attention

Comment: @Alexander Sure I do not know about that, now onwards will take care of that Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use Inetnts to navigate from one page to another page
and more over you shoul add activity for every class in the manifest.xml

if not trace out in the DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity3.this , Activity1.class);
startActivity(i);
```